# SwiftUI Recognize mouse hover

Tags: swiftui, mouse

For UIKit on Mac Catalyst (and soon on iPadOS with trackpad support in iOS 13.4) we can use the `UIHoverGestureRecognizer` to listen for mouse hover event and adjust view accordingly. On AppKit on macOS there is the `NSTrackingArea` for tracking the mouse cursor.

I can't seem to find a way to recognize the hover gesture in SwiftUI. In the [Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures) page of SwiftUI documentation there's only support for tap, long press, drag, magnification (zoom), and rotation. There is no indication of mouse hover.

Anyone have a way to do that?

The answer should preferably run natively on both iOS app (UIKit with `UIHostingController`) and macOS app (AppKit with `NSHostingController`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple just released the answer to this question alongside iOS 13.4!

Just use:

```
SomeView()
    .onHover { hover in
        print("Mouse hover: \(hover)")
        // Do something else
    }
```

Replace `SomeView` with your view, and that's it!

**Note:** Since this API came out from iOS 13.4, you cannot use this on apps that targets 13.0 (or you have cleverly use the `if` statement)

**UPDATE:** Looks like this had always worked on macOS (so don't have to specifically target 10.15.4, but I missed it :( )

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me when hovering over an Image in macOS 11.