# Detect when mouse hovering over a view in a Mac app

Tags: swift, macos

I thought this would be simple.

I have a small single window Mac app.
I want to detect when the mouse is hovering over the mainview of my app.
I believe I need to use "onHover"
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onhover(perform:)#declaration

I found this answer [SwiftUI Recognize mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750746/swiftui-recognize-mouse-hover) but it does't seem to work.

I declare the view:

```
@IBOutlet var mainView: NSView!
```

Then add the following code

```
mainView.onHover { hover in
    print("Mouse hover: \(hover)")
}
```

But it errors with Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'onHover'

Any guidance would be fantastic.

---

EDIT:  Im using the code given in the example on https://samoylov.eu/2016/09/05/mouseover-or-hover-effect-on-nsbutton-with-swift/

i'm declaring a button

```
@IBOutlet weak var startStopButton: NSButton!
```

then I added the code to track the rectangle

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set tracking area
        
    let area = NSTrackingArea.init(rect: startStopButton.bounds, options: [NSTrackingArea.Options.mouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingArea.Options.activeAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    startStopButton.addTrackingArea(area)
        
}
```

Then I added this code to the view

```
override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    print("Entered")
}
    
override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    print("Exited")
}
```

But errors with "Declaration 'mouseEntered(theEvent:)' has different argument labels from any potential overrides"

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: The answer your found is about SwiftUI, but you are not using SwiftUI.

Comment: Hint: NSEvent and enter

Comment: Thanks for the Hint! - I found an example on https://samoylov.eu/2016/09/05/mouseover-or-hover-effect-on-nsbutton-with-swift/

Comment: I spoke too soon, still can't get it to work. I edited the main question with my new code.

Comment: See [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingarea). "the owner of the tracking area receives `mouseEntered(with:)`, `mouseExited(with:)`, `mouseMoved(with:)`, and `cursorUpdate(with:)` messages"